# Prove that regular $T_1$ space is $T_2$ space.

Tags: general-topology

> Prove that regular $T_1$ space is $T_2$ space.

Definition of $T_1$: For all $a,b\in X$, there exist $A,B\in\tau$ s,t, $a\in A, b\notin A,b\in B,a\notin B$.

Definition of regular: For all $A\in \tau,x\in A$, there exist $U,V\in\tau$ s.t. $x\in U,X\setminus A\subset V$ s.t. $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

I don't know how to relate these 2 definition to show that $A\cap B=\emptyset$, please give me some idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:
If the space is $T_1$ then singletons are automatically closed sets. So if $x$ and $y$ are two distinct points then you can take $A=X-\{y\}$ as an open set that contains $x$.

Answer (score 3):

Let $a,b$ be distinct points of $X$.
Since $X$ is $T_1$, there exist $A,B$ open sets such that $A$ contains $a$ and not $b$, and $B$ contains $b$ and not $a$.

By regularity applied to the couple $(A,a)$, there exist two disjoint open sets $U,V$ such that $a\in U$ and $X\setminus A\subseteq V$. Since $b\not\in A$, $b\in X\setminus A$ hence $b\in V$. Thus, $U,V$ are two disjoint open sets such that $U$ contains $a$ and not $b$, and $V$ contains $b$ and not $a$, i.e. $X$ is $T_2$.

Note that I only used $A$, and not $B$ to prove that the space is Hausdorff. This means that $T_0$ and regular already implies that the space is Hausdorff.